# Understanding the term 'target' in python

Tags: python, shell, file, python-3.7, target

I'm working on exercise 16 in Zed Shaw's "Learn Python 3 the Hard Way". Most exercises he explains new terms when he introduces them into scripts, but in Exercise 16, he starts using the term without an explanation. 
To be more specific, the script instructs,

```
 "target = open(filename, 'w').
```

I understand most of this command--open the file and allow it to be written on--but I don't understand what role the term 'target' plays in this line of script. Could someone help me understand what this term means in this context?

Comment: "target" doesn't mean anything specific in Python. In any case, this website really isn't a "please explain LP3THW to me".  Questions need to be *self contained*. At the very least, you should provide a quote that you don't understand, or something. Don't cite some book and ask us to explain it to you. A warning, you'll find a relatively low opinion of Zed Shaw's books on here (one I don't necessarily share).

Comment: To be more specific, the script instructs,

 "target = open(filename, 'w').
I understand most of this command--open the file and allow it to be written on--but I don't understand what role the term 'target' plays in this line of script. Could someone help me understand what this term means in this context?

Comment: That is just a regular variable. It could have been `foo = open(filename, 'w')` or `banana = open(filename, 'w')` or whatever. Variable names can be arbitrary (as long as they aren't a key-word like `for`, because that is part of a language statement). Now, well written code will give variables descriptive names that help you read the code, and there are various conventional names, but don't be fooled, names can be whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you Juanpa!!!

Answer (score 0):

He's using `target` as a variable name for the file that the script is writing to.  If you were reading from one file and writing to another, you might refer to them as source and target files. It doesn't really have any special meaning beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

"target" is just a variable name. You can use any other variable name instead of "target" and it won't make any difference.

Comment: than you Roxy!!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, I am going through that book at the moment. the author is assuming the reader, by now, understands setting a variable to an input or setting an open file examples below

variable = open(filename)
variable = input("asking for details")

i.e
assigning a variable to an open file action
target = open(filename, 'w')

assigning a variable to an input action
variable = input("question")

Answer (score -1):

**Target** is only a variable and we use it when we need to compare different features of our dataset to this ***Target*** variable that is nothing but also one of the **feature** of our dataset. ***#feature stands for columns and Instance stands for rows in Machine learning***